# How to load a webp image with SDWebImage?

Tags: ios, sdwebimage, webp

I'm using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) to load images in my iOS app and I now want to use the webp format.

Here's my first try :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/2.webp"];

[self.imageView setImageWithURL:url
               placeholderImage:nil
                        options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload
 completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {

     if (error) {

         UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:error.localizedDescription delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

         [av show];
     }
 }];
```

It would work perfectly if the image was a jpeg (I tried) but with a webp it doesn't.
The first time I call this code the error is :

```
Downloaded image has 0 pixels
```

Then the error turns to :

```
The operation couldn't be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1100.)
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually the code above should work but the webp support is disabled by default in the library.

Adding `SD_WEBP=1` in the preprocessor macros of the sdwebimage target (in build settings) will enable webp support

Comment: could u post a source code how to use webp images in ios without taking much time to load them

Comment: Right answer but if u did not install webp submodule then it will give you an error message, so install pod "SDWebImage/WebP" before going to set preprocessor macros.

Answer (score 9):

Add

```
pod 'SDWebImage/WebP'
```

into your podfile and then hit pod install. Cocoapods is gonna take care of the preprocessor flag as well.

From SDWebImage [github page](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

> There are 3 subspecs available now: Core, MapKit and WebP (this means
>   you can install only some of the SDWebImage modules. By default, you
>   get just Core, so if you need WebP, you need to specify it).

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 5 and Xcode 11**

Use pod in podfile

```
pod 'SDWebImageWebPCoder'
```

Import this Library

```
import SDWebImageWebPCoder
```

Use this code under AppDelegate 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions'

```
let WebPCoder = SDImageWebPCoder.shared
SDImageCodersManager.shared.addCoder(WebPCoder)
```

use this code under ViewController 'viewDidLoad'

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //load from server
    let onlineFileUrl = URL(string: "http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/2.webp")
     //load from project directory
        let loaclFileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "2", withExtension: "webp")
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.imageView.sd_setImage(with: onlineFileUrl)
    }

}
```

Comment: it seems that webp file cannot be found through bundle. Any idea?

Comment: Actually, the problem is solved by manually adding the webp file into bundle. It can be done Project -> Bundle Phase -> copy bundle resouces

Answer (score 4):

I have searched many posts that finally lead to here.
And here is my solution after asking in github.

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/1122

Steps:

#### 1: `Clone` and add `WebP.framework`

clone the repository using `git clone --recursive https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage.git`

add full folder of `SDWebImage` and `WebP.framework` into your project.

[image]

#### 2: in `Build Settings` -- `Preprocessor Macros` , add `SD_WEBP=1`.

[image]

ps:If using `CocoaPods`, I don't konw how to add `WebP.framework` into `SDWebImage`, so I choose add files into my project.

Answer (score 1):

**Objective-C**

Use pod in podfile

```
pod 'SDWebImageWebPCoder'
```

Import this Library

```
#import <SDWebImageWebPCoder.h>
```

Use this code under AppDelegate 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions'

```
SDImageWebPCoder *WebPCoder = [SDImageWebPCoder sharedCoder];
[[SDImageCodersManager  sharedManager] addCoder:WebPCoder];
```

to download image

```
[self.yourImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your_url_webp" placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];
```